# Reading data in Java from text

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I'm trying to read the ex2data2.txt which contains dataset with 3 columns. I want to store it in my x array and y array. but it is not working. it cannot read the text file. the location of text file is in my src folder along with my codes.

```
    double[][] x = new double[180][1];
    double[][] y = new double[180][0];
       try{
           BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ex2data2.txt"));
           String words[]=new String[2];
           String line=null;
           int i = 0;
           while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
               words=line.split(",");
               //double[i] y = Double.parseDouble(words);
                x[i][0] = Double.parseDouble(words[0]);
                x[i][1] = Double.parseDouble(words[1]);
                y[i][0] = Double.parseDouble(words[2]);
           i++;
           }
           br.close();
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           System.err.println("Error: Target File Cannot Be Read");
       }
```

Comment: If it is throwing an exception, what is the exception? Why do you have a zero dimension for `y`?

Comment: Please paste your StackTrace

Comment: the exception is Target File cannot be read.
 because I will transform the y into matrix (Jama lib)

Comment: @RakeshKR what is StackTrace?

Comment: @user3065339 check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors  :-)

Comment: @RakeshKR by abusing `catch`, he discards his own error, to make debugging harder.

Comment: where I can found these stacktrace?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse That's Correct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should put the file in the top, parent project folder. not in src/**.

**Edit** : I have run this, for proof...

Accessing file, read all the data.

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "43 323 33" **this I have put in that file**

```
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
at com.rem.so.Rem.main(Rem.java:18)
```

**Next run**

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.rem.so.Rem.main(Rem.java:19)
```

**After correcting** this..

```
double[][] x = new double[180][2];
double[][] y = new double[180][1];
```

it is now done.

Please find the screenshot where I have put the file...

[image]

Comment: you mean inside the project folder?? still, it cannot be read.

Comment: As@Roger Rowland pointed out, why is your column size of y is 0? Are you getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ?

Comment: because i thought the first index of an array is 0.

Comment: Okay, so as @Anony-Mousse suggests, read a good java tutorial carefully. There will be lot of error handling in java, so by yourself you should not make any mistakes while coding.

Comment: sorry. I'm new to Java and I'm still learning. I don't know such things as that.

Answer (score 2):

```
catch(Exception e){
   System.err.println("Error: Target File Cannot Be Read");
}
```

Any developer writing this code should be immediately fired.

**Never** catch an `Exception`, but **perform proper and specific error handling**. Catch the most precise error to handle (e.g. `FileNotFoundException`), avoid catching errors that you do not know how to handle. If in doubt, *rethrow* the error, so that an outer error handler can process it. Always *log* the error, unless it is *expected* to happen.

Then you would be getting a more precise error message. But you opted to ignore the *actual* error `e`.

REALLY REALLY read a Java book or tutorial, in particular the section on proper exception handling. *You* are making your own live difficult by discarding the error the way you have been doing it.

An exception is almost *never* something you should ignore. You are required to handle them *for a reason*! (In fact, there are also "unchecked" exception, where you are not required to do so. Which makes it even more obvious that here, you *need* to handle them *properly*.)

[Three Rules for Effective Exception Handling (java.net)](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/04/exceptions.html)

---

Your error most likely is an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` (which you should not have caught!)

```
double[][] x = new double[180][1];
double[][] y = new double[180][0];
```

this is **too small**. you probably need

```
double[][] x = new double[180][2];
double[][] y = new double[180][1];
```

Answer (score 2):

double[][] y = new double[180][0];

That's probably not what you wanted. The second dimension is zero so you wont be able to put anything in that array. The second dimension needs to be at least 1.